# AVAudioRecorder! I need to have decibel values from amplitude on a scale of 0 to 120 ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder, amplitude

I'm getting amplitude values from -70 to around 10 from AVAudioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0).I need the values on a scale of 0 to 120 how i do it. I need to get the highest value in amplitude from the whole audio. 
Seen this code on internet

`var numver = 20 * log10(audioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))`

but this gives a value nan(Not a number).How can I get values of amplitude in positive range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function peakPowerForChannel() normally returns a logarithmically scaled decibel value from -160 dB to 0 dB.

It can return a value greater than zero when the power exceeds the level for 0 dB.

To convert to a linear scale for values from 0 to 120, please use the following formula.

```
let db = audioRecorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)
let result = pow(10.0, db / 20.0) * 120.0
```

You can choose whether to keep or discard values that exceed 120 with a max() or min() function.