# How to convert audioRecorder: AVRecorder from -160 to 0.0 to normal decibel values?

Tags: swift

How would i convert the values given to me from the audioRecorder, either .peakPower(0) or .averagePower(0) to decibels. Currently it gives a max of 0 and a min of -160. How would I get decibels then?

I have tried this post but it does not work.. [AVAudioRecorder! I need to have decibel values from amplitude on a scale of 0 to 120 ios swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918256/avaudiorecorder-i-need-to-have-decibel-values-from-amplitude-on-a-scale-of-0-to)

It gives out values of 1 which is almost impossible for a normal room.

Comment: the methods you mention give out *decibels full-scale (dBFS)*. Which "normal decibel values" are you referring to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate audio dB level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level)

Comment: @soundflix where the whispers are roughly 20 and speaking is approx 60. Loud noise is around 90.

Comment: I guess you mean sound pressure level (dB SPL). To get meaningful values you would need to calibrate your input. The [above question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level) have most of that covered.